# Is the isomorphism $V\to\mathbb K^{[\mathcal B]}$ always continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, normed-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

While trying to generalise the well-known result "continuous partials imply differentiability" to the case of infinite-dimensional spaces, the following question popped up in my work:

> Let $V$ be a normed linear space over $\mathbb K$ with a basis $\mathcal B$. Is the induced isomorphism $T\colon V\to \mathbb K^{[\mathcal B]}$ continuous (with respect to any given norm on $\mathbb K^{[\mathcal B]}$)?

It's clear that for any norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ on $\mathbb K^{[\mathcal B]}$, there exists a norm on $V$, namely, $v\mapsto \lVert Tv\rVert$, which makes $T$ continuous: Just note that $T$ is a linear map which is bounded.

Thus, due to equivalence of norms on finite-dimensional vector spaces, if $\dim V < \infty$, then the answer to the posed question is affirmative.

However, I am unable to comment anything for a general norm on an infinite-dimensional $V$. Any ideas?

Comment: Well you are just asking whether all norms on an infinite dimensional vector space are equivalent.  Have you seen a counterexample to that?

Comment: @EricWofsey Can you help me see how (the affirmative answer to) my question implies that all norms on an (infinite) dimensional space are equivalent? (I am not demanding $T^{-1}$ to be continuous.)

Comment: To get continuity of $T^{-1}$, just swap the norms that you are using on the domain and codomain.

Comment: @EricWofsey Took some time, but got it! Thanks.